# Symmetric group subgroups correct relations

Tags: group-theory

Denote $S_n$ symmetric group on $n$ numbers.

$S_n=\cup_{i=1}^{n-1}S_i\times S_{n-i}$ is obviously not correct. If you want to relate $S_n$ to its symmetric subgroups, what is the correct relation?

Comment: It is very unclear exactly what you are asking, but the answer is probably that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

$S_k$ sits inside $S_n$ for $k < n$ in many different ways.

The "obvious" embedding $S_k \hookrightarrow S_n$ given by sending a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to the same permutation, but leaving $\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$ fixed, is just one of many other possibilities.

First of all, it is not "canonical" to let $\sigma$ permute the first $k$ numbers of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Given any embedding $\tau:S_k \to S_n$, you get a new one by composing with other elements $\tau' \in S_k$ and $\sigma' \in S_n$. In other words, if $\tau$ is **one** such embedding, then $\sigma' \tau \tau'$ is also one.